# Rendering a glyph vector with a large font size

Tags: java, fonts, java-2d, graphics2d

For a project I'm working on, I need to render text of varying font-size on a canvas, sometimes several times. To do this I'm creating a glyph vector, and drawing that using Graphics2D.

```
font = new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
glyphs = font.createGlyphVector(frc, text);

...

g2.setColor(word.getColor());
g2.drawGlyphVector(word.getGlyphs(), (float)word.getPosition().getX(), (float)word.getPosition().getY());
```

This has been working fine up until recently, when I noticed that large font sizes (anything above 100) can't be rendered. The glyph vector appears to be created without issue, and looks to be accurate for the text I'm expecting to render. It seems that Graphics2D takes issue with rendering the glyphs.

I've checked this with a multitude of font faces, and everything seems to have a hard limit of exactly 100. I've been unable to find any mention of a cap after a fair amount of googling.

Are there any known issues with rendering glyph vectors with large font sizes using Graphics2D?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use glyphs.getOutline() and render the obtained shape?

Actually I tried glyph vectors rendering and dont' remember any problems with big fonts. Could you post a compilable code to show the problem?

Comment: Hi, I've just noticed this is a problem specific to my development platform (Fedora). While trying to mock up some example code I'm having no issues on my Windows machine. I'll have to look in to this further but this at least indicates it's not a fault with the glyph vector itself...